# Animation example doesn't work on IE10. Does on Chrome

Tags: css-animations, internet-explorer-10

The animation on this MDN page works in Chrome, but not in IE10.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onanimationend

I am asking because my own animation (much more complicated) works fine in Chrome but not in IE10.  Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

After some more research, I kinda-sorta know the answer.

My code fails because when I write a replacement style sheet using the techniques described in the mdn article below, it works in Chrome but not in IE10.  When I don't rewrite the style sheet, but use the one I started out with, it works.

https://www.w3.org/wiki/Dynamic_style_-_manipulating_CSS_with_JavaScript

The "Accessing style sheets" section.

I'd still like to know why IE10 behaves this way.